# Use ImageDataGenerator with TensorFlow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a pipeline for image recognition with TensorFlow (v2.5). Usually, I download the data and save it locally in a directory structure similar to the one recommended by the Keras documentation (e.g. [here](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)). For data augmentation, I really like using the [ImageDataGenerator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator). As I have the data stored in a directory, I can use the `flow_from_directory` method. I know that this procedure may not be recommended for very large datasets, but so far it has worked well for me.

My problem is that now I would like to use my same pipeline with [TensorFlow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview) to benchmark my models. Obviously, the `flow_from_directory` method no longer works because I am loading a dataset object. I have tried many alternatives, including casting the dataset as a Pandas data frame and using the `flow_from_frame` method instead, but that requires strings only for both `x_col` and `y_col` (which I find very strange).

At the moment, I am stuck and my code looks as follows. Any help, including a complete change of method, is very welcome. I am aware of the alternative mapping functions for image augmentation or the Keras layers; however, I would like to try to make it happen with the [ImageDataGenerator API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam  #RMSprop #Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


#if not os.path.exists("/root/tensorflow_datasets/beans"):
#    os.makedirs("/root/tensorflow_datasets/beans")

# Load the "beans" tensorflow dataset into distinct training and test subsets:
(train_ds, test_ds), ds_info = tfds.load('beans', split=['train', 'test'],
                              as_supervised=True,download=True,
                              with_info=True)
                              #,data_dir="~/tensorflow_datasets/beans") 

# Get information on the size of the training and test sets:
train_ds_size = sum(1 for _ in train_ds)
print("No. elements in training set: " + str(train_ds_size))
test_ds_size = sum(1 for _ in test_ds)
print("No. elements in test set: " + str(test_ds_size))

df_train = tfds.as_dataframe(train_ds, ds_info)
df_test  = tfds.as_dataframe(test_ds, ds_info)

# Perform data augmentation with the image generators:
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

# N.B.: No changes to the test set!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Convert the labels to strings: - try to fix problem with y_col
df_train['label'] = df_train['label'].astype(str)
df_test['label'] = df_test['label'].astype(str)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator:
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        df_train,  
        x_col="image",
        y_col="label",
        target_size=(500, 500), #less?
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='categorical') #categorical layer

# Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator:
train_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        df_test,  
        x_col="image",
        y_col="label",
        target_size=(500, 500), #less?
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='categorical') #categorical layer
```

And here is error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-827a1a63828e> in <module>()
     24         target_size=(500, 500), #less?
     25         batch_size=20,
---> 26         class_mode='categorical') #categorical layer
     27 
     28 # Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator:

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py in _check_params(self, df, x_col, y_col, weight_col, classes)
    190         if not all(df[x_col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
    191             raise TypeError('All values in column x_col={} must be strings.'
--> 192                             .format(x_col))
    193         # check labels are string if class_mode is binary or sparse
    194         if self.class_mode in {'binary', 'sparse'}:

TypeError: All values in column x_col=image must be strings.
```

Comment: I didn't understand why `flow_from_directory` no longer works. Anyway, x_col and y_col should be set with strings (column names) which makes sense. And y_col values does not need to be strings, but x_col values should be strings since they are storing image_names or paths. The error indicates that at least 1 `image` column value is not in string format.